# Horizontal scroll bar bot working in bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a modal, showing div in 'modal-body'.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="scoll-tree">
        <div class="history">
            Report Event Details
        </div>
        <div class="history">
            Report Event Details 1
        </div>
       <div class="history">
            Report Event Details 2
        </div>
       <div class="history">
            Report Event Details 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Set the class as bellow :

```
.scoll-tree{
   width: 400px;
   height:80px;
   overflow-x: scroll;
}

.history {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    float: left;
    min-width: 5em;
    width: 25ex;
    max-height: 3em;
    margin: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    vertical-align: central;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I want horizontal scroll bar to `'scoll-tree'` container,  when `'history'` div exceed the width.

Currently it give vertical scroll bar, i want only horizontal scroll bar.

https://jsfiddle.net/hemantmalpote/4duq2svh/35/

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/t9tr2kqz/

Comment: @XYZ : you had given same fiddle.
It just give vertical scroll bar not a horizontal.

Comment: remove  or increase the height of scoll-tree class to avoid vertical scroll in @XYZ's latest fiddle

Comment: @XYZ: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
     
     
     <div style="height:100px; width:100px; overflow-x:auto">
Content1
Content2
Content3
Content4
Content5
Content6
Content7
Content8
Content9
Content10
</div>


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure whether it is what you are looking for, but check it https://jsfiddle.net/4duq2svh/44/. I changed you css little bit,

```
.modal-body {
    width: 400px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.scoll-tree{
   width: 800px;//ideally you it is better to make js script which will calculate this value
   height:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple - 
Just use ***max-width*** instead of ***width*** & set `overflow-x: auto`.
So it will be -

```
.scoll-tree{
   max-width: 400px;
   height:80px;
   overflow-x: auto;
}
```

You may first set it to 200px for testing whether scroll appears or not.